# font on bootstrap 5 navbar different from the rest of the site

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, frontend, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website. While I was creating this website I needed to create a thank you page and I found one online in someone's [codepen](https://codepen.io/) This is the codepen project I found [here](https://codepen.io/Grett/pen/byvRZq) so I copied the code into a HTML file on vscode. Then I started adding things to the code I already created before such as the navbar and footer. I noticed that something was changing the font of the text on my navbar and footer so I tried to use CSS to fix it. This is what it's supposed to look like [image]

This is what it looks like now [image]

### Test.html

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Thank You | </title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400|Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/thank-you.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        @import url(//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css);
        @import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://2-22-4-dot-lead-pages.appspot.com/static/lp918/min/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://2-22-4-dot-lead-pages.appspot.com/static/lp918/min/html5shiv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
        <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" alt="  logo" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
    </a>

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
        title="Toggle Menu"
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navmenu"
    >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    </button>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link  text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
            // Get the Services dropdown link element
            const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
          
            // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
              window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            });
          
            // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
              // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
              });
          
              // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
              });
            }
          </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
    </div>

</nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
    <!-- THANK YOU MESSAGE START -->
    
    <header class="site-header" id="header">
        <h1 class="site-header__title" data-lead-id="site-header-title">THANK YOU!</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="main-content text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-check main-content__checkmark fa-5x " id="checkmark"></i>
        <p class="main-content__body mb-5" data-lead-id="main-content-body">Thanks a bunch for filling out this form. It means a lot to us, just like you do! We will reach out to you shortly have a nice day!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- THANK YOU MESSAGE CLOSE -->

    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
<footer class="bg-dark text-white " id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>About Us</h4>
          <hr />
          <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.
  
          </p>
          <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
  
          <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
          
          
          </a>
  
          <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
            
          <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
          </a>
          <!-- <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
          </a> -->
  
          <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
          <!-- <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
          </a> -->
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Quick Links</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Contact Info</h4>
          <hr />
          <p>
            City, State Zip <br />
            Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />
            example@email.com
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
      Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";
html p {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    
    
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fffffe;
}
body {
    padding: 0 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: #fffffe;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}

}

.site-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.site-header__title {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.main-content__checkmark {
    font-size: 4.0625rem;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #24b663;
    
}
.main-content__body {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.site-footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.site-footer__fineprint {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: 300;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .site-header {
        padding-top: 150px;
    }
    .site-header__title {
        font-size: 6.25rem;
    }
    .main-content__checkmark {
        font-size: 9.75rem;
    }
    .main-content__body {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    .site-footer {
        padding: 145px 0 25px;
    }
    .site-footer__fineprint {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }
}

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .carousel-inner{
     
     }
   }
```

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";
html p {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    
    
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #fffffe;
}
body {
    padding: 0 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: #fffffe;
    color: #1a1a1a;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}

}

.site-header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0 0;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.site-header__title {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    hyphens: auto;
}

.main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.main-content__checkmark {
    font-size: 4.0625rem;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #24b663;
    
}
.main-content__body {
    margin: 20px 0 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.site-footer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0 25px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 820px;
}
.site-footer__fineprint {
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    line-height: 1.3;
    font-weight: 300;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) {
    .site-header {
        padding-top: 150px;
    }
    .site-header__title {
        font-size: 6.25rem;
    }
    .main-content__checkmark {
        font-size: 9.75rem;
    }
    .main-content__body {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
    .site-footer {
        padding: 145px 0 25px;
    }
    .site-footer__fineprint {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }
}

#sub-header {
    color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M4.646 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708l-6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L10.293 8 4.646 2.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.carousel-control-prev-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16' fill='hsl(18, 100%, 62%)'%3e%3cpath d='M11.354 1.646a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708L5.707 8l5.647 5.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708l6-6a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

#button {
    background-color:hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
    border-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .nav-link::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    .nav-link:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .carousel-inner{
     
     }
   }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Thank You | </title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400|Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/thank-you.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        @import url(//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.min.css);
        @import url(//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://2-22-4-dot-lead-pages.appspot.com/static/lp918/min/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://2-22-4-dot-lead-pages.appspot.com/static/lp918/min/html5shiv.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
        <img src="./assets/logo-topnav.png" alt="  logo" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
    </a>

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <button
        title="Toggle Menu"
        type="button"
        class="navbar-toggler"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navmenu"
    >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
    </button>
    <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

    <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link  text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/services.html" role="button"  aria-expanded="false" id="servicesDropdown">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-capitalize text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white text-capitalize" href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
            // Get the Services dropdown link element
            const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
          
            // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
              window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            });
          
            // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
              // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
              });
          
              // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
              });
            }
          </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
    </div>

</nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
    <!-- THANK YOU MESSAGE START -->
    
    <header class="site-header" id="header">
        <h1 class="site-header__title" data-lead-id="site-header-title">THANK YOU!</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="main-content text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-check main-content__checkmark fa-5x " id="checkmark"></i>
        <p class="main-content__body mb-5" data-lead-id="main-content-body">Thanks a bunch for filling out this form. It means a lot to us, just like you do! We will reach out to you shortly have a nice day!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- THANK YOU MESSAGE CLOSE -->

    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
<footer class="bg-dark text-white " id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>About Us</h4>
          <hr />
          <p>We are skilled IT professionals who specialize in solving a range of problems that our clients may face in the realm of IT.
  
          </p>
          <!-- FACEBOOK SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>
          </a>
  
          <!-- INSTAGRAM SECTION  -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2x"></i>
          
          
          </a>
  
          <!-- TWITTER SECTION -->
          <a href="">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
            
          <!-- LINKEDIN SECTION -->
          </a>
          <!-- <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i>
          </a> -->
  
          <!-- WHATSAPP SECTION -->
          <!-- <a href="#">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>
          </a> -->
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Quick Links</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/services.html" class="nav-link">Services</a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Privacy and Terms</h4>
          <hr />
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Terms & Coniditions</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">API Documentation</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 mt-5">
          <h4>Contact Info</h4>
          <hr />
          <p>
            City, State Zip <br />
            Call Us Now 123-456-7890 <br />
            example@email.com
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-dark text-white text-center py-4" id="copyright">
      Copyright &copy; 2023 . All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- FOOTER SECTION CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The images you show don't appear to have come from the snippet that you included. It would be more helpful if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Keyword: minimal. Not the whole page.

Comment: @TimR ok I fixed it it sorry

Comment: When I run the snippet, the nav links appear to have a normal font weight just like the first image, not bold like the second image.